# Can't edit an attribute, error Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never' with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, types

I want to edit an attribute from an object in TypeScript and React but I get the following error:
`Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'` despite the fact that I check the type of this attribute before :

```
const familySetter = (newValue: string, attributeToSet: keyof Family) => {
    setNewFamily((currNewFam) => {
      if (!currNewFam) return;
      const newNewFam: Family = { ...currNewFam };
      if (typeof newNewFam[attributeToSet] === 'string') {

        newNewFam[attributeToSet] = newValue; //error at this line

      }
      return newNewFam;
    });
  };
```

Comment: Could you add the `Family` type/interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will occured when your class properties have several types (for sample string and number)

```
class Family {
    test: string;
    test2: number;
};
```

in that case the compilator will not know if `newNewFam[attributeToSet]` is of one type or another

one solution is to declare your method by extending the keyof Family and say value is of type `Family[K]`

```
const familySetter = <K extends keyof Family>(newValue: Family[K], attributeToSet: K)
```

the if `if (typeof newNewFam[attributeToSet] === 'string')` is not enought because it's evaluate at runtime dependings on function parameter

complete sample is

```
class Family {
    test: string;
    test2: number;
};

const familySetter = <K extends keyof Family>(newValue: Family[K], attributeToSet: K) => {
    setNewFamily((currNewFam) => {
      if (!currNewFam) return;
      const newNewFam: Family = { ...currNewFam };
      if (typeof newNewFam[attributeToSet] === 'string') {
        newNewFam[attributeToSet] = newValue; 
      }
      return newNewFam;
    });
  };
```

Comment: By the way, with this code I can even remove the `if (typeof newNewFam[attributeToSet] === 'string') `  verification ?

Comment: yes normally you can remove the condition but depending on the functional need you have. Here the method only affect the Family property when it type is string